# Php require() does not recognize aliased class

Tags: php, php-closures

So mainly this is caused by my code structure:

File1.php

```
use \Class1 as Blah;
require 'File2.php';
```

File2.php

```
$closure = function ($arg) {
    return new Blah($arg);
};
```

Somehow the part behind `... as` isn't recognized after using `require()`.

Comment: if you require the file out-side the anonymous function's scope, its accessible to the developer in that environment either way so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @KDOT Let me edit this, I've found out, that this not a problem related to Slim itself. I is caused by the fact that the "use SomeClass as \Another" is not recognized by the code included using "require()"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespace aliases are only valid **within the file in which you write the `use` statement.** The aliases do not transfer across file boundaries. If you want to `use Class1 as Blah` within File2.php, you need to put that statement at the top of File2.php.

Comment: I don't know how you worded that so easily... +1

Comment: Thanks! I just found another question and apparently I just didn't know what exactly I was searching for in the first place. If I think about it, it makes perfect sense to handle it this way

Answer (score 0):

> ***is not recognized by the code*** - Slim is not a compiler, it is a framework.

The code will execute to the PHP compiler standards, therefore using the default.

```
use SomeNamespace\SomeClass as SomePrefix;
```

Will work no matter what you're trying to achieve. The `require_once()` method loads your PHP file holding the class, which I assume doesn't have a custom namespace since you're targeting the `\` directory.

If you're working inside a class then this might be your issue, your code should run similar to this after using the `require_once()` to load in the `ParseMarkdownClass` file.

```
use ParseMarkdownClass as Md;

class SomeClass
{
    public $container;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->container = (object)['m' => function() {
            return new Md();
        }];
    }
}

(new SomeClass())->$container->m()->...
```